# How to force landscape orientation in iOS for specific camera view controller

Tags: ios, camera, storyboard, screen-orientation

I have read a lot on this topic but am not satisfied with my current solution.

I am creating a capture app that is primarily in portrait mode but I would like to force the camera view to be in landscape.

I've been using these simple functions to force the orientation to change in viewWillAppear in my capture view controller.

```
static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask) { 
    if let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate {
      delegate.orientationLock = orientation
    }
}

static func lockOrientation(_ orientation: UIInterfaceOrientationMask, andRotateTo rotateOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientation) {

    self.lockOrientation(orientation)

    UIDevice.current.setValue(rotateOrientation.rawValue, forKey: "orientation")
}
```

One issue is that the view controller still initially visibly loads in portrait and then rotates itself into landscape.

How do I force it to appear in landscape so that it never appears in portrait?

In the future, I may like to use portrait capture as well with behavior much like the default camera app (icons rotate but the capture button and preview remain the same. photos come out in the correct orientation). I'd like to design this interface in the storyboard so I can see both portrait and landscape views in storyboard by changing the device orientation.

How can I make the camera screen handle genuine device orientation change in the storyboard? I have found no clean solutions to doing this.